# Access data in var variable after deserializing json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a problem I am trying to deserialize json string to object the method what I have used is the below one.

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json1);
var pc= dict["getresults"];
```

Now I am able to parse the data and store it in var variable "PC" has key value-pair, but can anyone tell me how to retreive data from the PC this might be easy but I am facing difficulty in doing this.

Comment: You need to convert object to a particular type to be able to browse it's properties etc. Otherwise use Reflection.

Can you Deserialize to a Dictionary<string, {ParticularType}> instead of Dictionary<string, object> ?

Comment: You are deserializing to a dictionary, so use the dictionary methods and properties to access your data. If you have a class that matches the signature of your serialized data, you could deserialize it into that object. The latter approach is what I would suggest in normal circumstances.

Comment: now i am not able to deserialize to a particular type

Comment: @hbulens can u post a link or small example for the later part solution u told

Comment: Could you post your json1 variable first? The structure of your JSON will determine the structure of your .NET class in order to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDict=(Dictionary<string, object>)dict;
```

OR

```
var pc=(object)dict["getresults"];
```

Comment: how shall i retreive values from pc

Answer (score 0):

How does your JSON look like?
For example if it's something like this:

```
"{\"getresults\": {\"apple\": \"true\", \"orange\": \"false\"}}"
```

Then you may want to use something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> a = (Dictionary<string, object>)pc;
if((bool)a["apple"])
{
    /*Do something.*/
}
```